# displayName() inner function is returned from the outer function before being executed

Tags: javascript, closures

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

```
function makeFunc() {
  var name = 'Mozilla';
  function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }
  return displayName;
}

var myFunc = makeFunc();
myFunc();
```

> What's different (and interesting) is that the displayName() inner function is returned from the outer function before being executed.

How is outer function not getting executed? Outer function is makeFunc() and displayName() is inner function. I can see "Mozilla" being printed. Doesn't that mean that first `makeFunc` is getting executed and then `displayName`?

What's the point that I am missing?

Comment: The outer function *is* getting executed. You've misunderstood - the "before being executed" in that paragraph refers to the inner function, not the outer.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I got it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`makeFunc` is called and it creates the `name` variable and the `displayName` function, and returns `displayName`. When you call `makeFunc` it creates, but doesn't execute, the inner function. By the time you call `myFunc`, the `name` variable from inside `makeFunc` is gone, but, since `displayName` referenced it, `myFunc` is a closure that also holds the value of `name` from when the closure was created.

Answer (score 1):

When you invoking makeFunc you are creating a scoped function displayName, which has acces to the current value of name. Then makeFunc returns this function. It will not be executed, it is handled similar to objects.
You can pass the function around. Or execute it explicitly as you do in your last statement.